# Как правильно сохранять картинки в память телефона?

Tags: java, android

Собственно сабж. Как я понял, желательно создавать отдельную папку для своего приложения и сохранять туда изображения(Vk, Telegram, Whatsup и т.д.). Видел много информации, что нельзя создавать программно папки, если в телефоне нет SD карты. Вообщем какой правильный алгоритм сохранения изображения в память девайса?

Вот к чему я пришёл. Поправьте, если не правильно:

1)Проверка на наличие спец. папки в памяти телефона

2)Если нет папки, проверка на наличие SD карты

3)Если есть SD карта, то сохранить на неё, если нет - во внутреннее хранилище

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import android.os.Environment;

File imageRoot;
String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

// Проверяем наличие внешнего хранилища и доступность для записи
if(storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    // Получаем подкаталог для нашего приложения в общем каталоге изображений
    imageRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), 'MegaApp'); 
}
else {
    // Получаем подкаталог для изображений в каталоге файлов нашего приложения
    imageRoot = new File(getFilesDir(), 'images');
}

imageRoot.mkdirs(); // Создаём каталог, если его нет
```